# Cursor not returning to its default State

Tags: javascript, asp.net, cursor, busy-cursor

I want to show busy cursor while downloading. and its working as expected but after click event ends still cursor showing busy. I want to roll back to its default after download completed i.e. after click events ended.

on Page load :

```
btnGenerate.Attributes.Add("onclick", "waitdownload();");
```

Aspx :

```
<script>
   function waitdownload() {
       document.body.style.cursor = "wait";
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a Timeout that waits x second to execute another piece of code.

```
<script>
    function waitdownload() {
        document.body.style.cursor = "wait";

        //wait 5 seconds to set the cursor to default
        setTimeout(function () {
            document.body.style.cursor = "default";
        }, 5000);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Its working for 5 sec but my requirement is once downloaded gets completed then it should come it default state

Comment: That's another story.... You don't know when the client is finished downloading. That all depends on the file size and connection speed. So get the average dowload time and set the timer to that (if the files are downloadable withing a reasonable time)

Comment: You are correct but what i did after completion of file redirected to same page so its stop showing busy cursor href="Webform1.aspx?download=1"